# Prediction using Recurrent Neural Network on Time series dataset

Tags: statistics, neural-network, time-series, prediction, pybrain

**Description**

Given a dataset that has 10 sequences - a sequence corresponds to a day of stock value recordings - where each constitutes 50 sample recordings of stock values that are separated by 5 minute intervals starting from the morning or 9:05 am. However, there is one extra recording (the 51th sample) that is only available in the training set which is 2 hours later, not 5 minutes, than the  last recorded sample in the 50 sample recordings. That 51th sample is required to be predicted for the testing set where the first 50 samples are also given.

I am using the `pybrain` recurrent neural network for this problem that groups sequences together, and the label (or commonly known as the target `y`)  of each sample `x_i` is the sample of the next time step `x_(i+1)` - a typical formulation in time series prediction.

**Example**

```
A sequence for one day is something like:

    Signal id    Time      value
        1     -  9:05   -   23
        2     -  9:10   -   31
        3     -  9:15   -   24
       ...    -  ...    -   ...
       50     -  13:15  -   15

Below is the 2 hour later label 'target' given for the training set 
and is required to be predicted for the testing set
       51     -  15:15   -   11
```

**Question**

Now that my recurrent neural network (RNN) has trained on these 10 sequences, if it confronts another sequence, how would I use the `RNN` to predict the stock values `2 hours` after the last sample in the sequence ?

Please note that I also have "2 hours later than the last sample stock values" for each of the training sequences but I am not sure how to incorporate that in  training the `RNN` since it expects identical time intervals between samples. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't quite understand your explanation. Does all your training set values contain 50 input signals, and it is the same time delta between all the samples? Is your question actually: `How do you predict the next sequence output` ?

Comment: Yes the first 50 input signals have the same time delta - 5 minute difference, however, for each sequence there are in fact 51 input signals, the last signal has a much larger delta - 2 hours difference - than the rest, and I'm required to predict that last signal given the first 50 signals. So the questions are how to train the `RNN` with a signal that is of different delta than others and how to predict that signal given the first 50 signals.

Comment: @jorgenkg, I have updated the question to clarify, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*I hope I this will help you out*

## The recurrent network structure

[image]

---

## A few tips

#### Choosing your recurrent network

The more mature Long Short Time Memory (LSTM) neural network is a great fit for this kind of task. LSTM is able to detect common "shapes" and "variations" in the stock value "graph", and there is A LOT of research which tries to prove that such shapes actually occur in real life! [See this link for an example](http://www.investopedia.com/university/technical/techanalysis8.asp).

#### Accuracy

If you want the network to achieve higher accuracy, I would recommend you to also feed the network the stock values from the previous year (at the exact same date), so that the number of inputs doubles from 50 to 100. Though the network might be well optimised on your dataset, it will never be able to predict the unpredictable behaviour of the future ;)

Comment: Thanks a tonne, wonderful description! One small concern though,  since only around the first half of the samples and  the last sample (the 50th) have a `two hour later` target sample, is it okay to combine them together in a sequence in `LSTM`? because the first half of the samples are 5 minutes apart but the last sample (the 50th sample) is far from that first half, what do you think? The 51th sample is the `2 hour later` value for the 50th sample.

Comment: That shouldn't be  a problem in theory. Just make sure you have *enough* data samples! It should probably contain at least 20.000 entries (split into 2/3 `training set` and 1/3 v`alidation set`) to ensure a more accurate and robust network! Best wishes!

Comment: I am also curious is the alternative way to LSTM is including lagged variables?

Comment: Did you create the image yourself? If not, could you please provide a source? This is visually one of the best images avoiding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Yes, I made it with Omnigraffle but that file is unfortunately deleted