# Time Series Prediction using Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I am using a [Bike Sharing dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bike+Sharing+Dataset) to predict the number of rentals in a day, given the input. I will use 2011 data to train and 2012 data to validate. I successfully built a linear regression model, but now I am trying to figure out how to predict time series by using Recurrent Neural Networks.

Data set has 10 attributes (such as month, working day or not, temperature, humidity, windspeed), all numerical, though an attribute is day (Sunday: 0, Monday:1 etc.).

I assume that one day can and probably will depend on previous days (and I will not need all 10 attributes), so I thought about using RNN. I don't know much, but I read some stuff and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670558/prediction-using-recurrent-neural-network-on-time-series-dataset). I think about a structure like this.

I will have `10 input neurons`, `a hidden layer` and `1 output neuron`.  I don't know how to decide on how many neurons the hidden layer will have.

I guess that I need a matrix to connect input layer to hidden layer, a matrix to connect hidden layer to output layer, and a matrix to connect hidden layers in neighbouring time-steps, `t-1` to `t`, `t` to `t+1`. That's total of 3 matrices.

In one tutorial, activation function was `sigmoid`, although I'm not sure exactly, if I use sigmoid function, I will only get output between 0 and 1. What should I use as activation function? My plan is to repeat this for `n` times:

- For each training data:

  - **Forward propagate**

    - Propagate the input to hidden layer, add it to propagation of previous hidden layer to current hidden layer. And pass this to activation function.
    - Propagate the hidden layer to output.
    - Find error and its derivative, store it in a list
  - **Back propagate**

    - Find current layers and errors from list
    - Find current hidden layer error
    - Store weight updates
  - Update weights (matrices) by multiplying them by learning rate.

Is this the correct way to do it? I want real numerical values as output, instead of a number between 0-1.

Comment: Have you considered using ready packages for RNNs like e.g. Keras in Python? That could make your task easier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the correct way to do it, if you are just wanting to learn the basics. If you want to build a neural network for practical use, this is a very poor approach and as Marcin's comment says, almost everyone who constructs neural nets for practical use do so by using packages which have an ready simulation of neural network available. Let me answer your questions one by one...

1. *I don't know how to decide on how many neurons the hidden layer will have.*

There is no golden rule to choose the right architecture for your neural network. There are many empirical rules people have established out of experience, and the right number of neurons are decided by trying out various combinations and comparing the output. A good starting point would be (3/2 times your input plus output neurons, i.e. (10+1)*(3/2)... so you could start with a 15/16 neurons in hidden layer, and then go on reducing the number based on your output.)

2. *What should I use as activation function?*

Again, there is no 'right' function. It totally depends on what suits your data. Additionally, there are many types of sigmoid functions like hyperbolic tangent, logistic, RBF, etc. A good starting point would be logistic function, but again you will only find the right function through trial and error.

3. *Is this the correct way to do it? I want real numerical values as output, instead of a number between 0-1.*

All activation functions(including the one assigned to output neuron) will give you an output of 0 to 1, and you will have to use multiplier to convert it to real values, or have some kind of encoding with multiple output neurons. Coding this manually will be complicated.

Another aspect to consider would be your training iterations. Doing it 'n' times doesn't help. You need to find the optimal training iterations with trial and error as well to avoid both under-fitting and over-fitting.

The correct way to do it would be to use packages in Python or R, which will allow you to train neural nets with large amount of customization quickly, where you can train and test multiple nets with different activation functions (and even different training algorithms) and network architecture without too much hassle. With some amount of trial and error, you will eventually find the net that gives you desirable output.

Comment: I mean, I could probably use a readily available package but it's just an assignment and I want to learn thoroughly. I can implement this one and compare the result to results of packages.

I can try implementing, and by changing *n*, *dimension of hidden layer*, *activation function* and *alpha* I can try to optimize results. Thing is, as I have said, output values. In the dataset, avg of output is 3405. What if I don't use sigmoid function when propagating from hidden layer to output? Can I just multiply the weights with hidden layer? What about initial neural network weights?

Comment: If you don't use a sigmoid function, then mathematically your multi-layered network can be reduced to a single layer network by multiplying all the weights and eventually making it a linear equation... the resultant model would be the same as an regression model which would kind of defeat the point of neural network... You could of course do that to compare how your trained network performs against regression model... But the hidden layer would be totally pointless...

Comment: If you're in R, the caret package let's you do a grid search across a range of network parameters: number of neurons, number of layers, activations functions, repeats, learning rate.